# Max. distance of Normal to ellipse from origin

Tags: analytic-geometry

How Can I calculate Maximum Distance of Center of the ellipse $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ from the Normal.

My Try ::  Let $P(a\cos \theta,b\sin \theta)$ be any point on the ellipse. Then equation of Normal at that point is

$ax\sec \theta-by\csc \theta = a^2-b^2$. Then How can I find Max. distance of Center of the ellipse from the Normal

Comment: "The" normal? What normal? At what point on the ellipse?

Comment: I suppose that he wants normals at all points on ellipse and then to choose the one which is more distant from center of the ellipse.

Comment: Yes DonAntonio and point on ellipse

Comment: As zaarcis suggests, the question here is probably to compute the distance between the center and each normal, and then find the maximum of all these distances. For the first step, see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html.

Comment: To julien I have one Question. Distance of point $P(x_{1},y_{1})$ to line $ax+by+c = 0$ is $=\displaystyle \left|\frac{ax_{1}+by_{1}+c}{a^2+b^2}\right|$ which is a Minimum distance but How can I calculate for Maximum

Comment: @juantheron The maximum distance between a point and the points on a line is always $+\infty$. When we talk about the distance between a point $p$ and a line $L$, it means the minimum of $\|p-q\|$ where $q$ runs over all points of $L$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the distance of the normal from the origin $(0,0)$ is $$\left| \frac{a^2-b^2}{\sqrt{(a\sec\theta)^2+(-b\csc\theta)^2}} \right|$$

So, we need to minimize $(a\sec\theta)^2+(-b\csc\theta)^2=a^2\sec^2\theta+b^2\csc^2\theta=f(\theta)$(say)

So, $\frac{df}{d\theta}=a^22\sec\theta\sec\theta\tan\theta+b^22\csc\theta(-\csc\theta\cot\theta)=2a^2\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^3\theta}-2b^2\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^3\theta}$

For the extreme value of $f(\theta),\frac{df}{d\theta}=0$

$\implies 2a^2\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^3\theta}-2b^2\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^3\theta}=0$ or $\tan^4\theta=\frac{b^2}{a^2}$

Assuming $a>0,b>0$, $\tan^2\theta=\frac ba$

Now, $\frac{d^2f}{d\theta^2}=2a^2\left(\frac1{\cos^2\theta}+\frac{3\sin^2\theta}{\cos^4\theta}\right)+2b^2\left(\frac1{\sin^2\theta}+\frac{3\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\right)>0$ for real $\theta$

So, $f(\theta)$ will attain the minimum value at $\tan^2\theta=\frac ba$

So, $f(\theta)_\text{min}=a^2\sec^2\theta+b^2\csc^2\theta_{\text{at  }\tan^2\theta=\frac ba}=a^2\left(1+\frac ba\right)+b^2\left(1+\frac ab\right)=(a+b)^2$

So, the minimum value of $\sqrt{(a\sec\theta)^2+(-b\csc\theta)^2}$ is $a+b$

If $\tan\theta=\sqrt \frac ba, \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt b}=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt a}=\pm\frac1{b+a}$

If $\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt b}{a+b}\implies \csc\theta=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt b},\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt a}{a+b}\implies \sec\theta=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt a}$

There will be another set $(\csc\theta=-\frac{a+b}{\sqrt b},\sec\theta=-\frac{a+b}{\sqrt a})$

There will be two more set of values of $(\csc\theta,\sec\theta)$ for $\tan\theta=-\sqrt\frac ba$

So, we shall have four normals having the maximum distance from the origin.

Comment: Thanks lab bhattacharjee but This is a perpendicular Distance which is always Minimum So How can i Maximise that.

Comment: @juantheron, distance implicitly means the perpendicular one. This answer calculates which normal has the maximum (perpendicular) distance from the origin.

Comment: So the maximum distance is $\dfrac{a-b}{a+b}$

Comment: @zaarcis, the maximum distance will be $\left|\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b} \right|=\mid a-b\mid$

Comment: My fault. Forget about square root.

Answer (score -3):

let a point p(acost,bsint) is on the ellipse.
x2/a2 y2/b2=1
dy/dx=-b2x/a2y

dy/dx of normal on(acost,bsint)
= a2y/b2x=a/btant
equestion of normal
y-bsint=b/atant(x-acost)
axsect-bycost-(a2-b2)=0

now
lenth from origin(0,0) of the normal
l=mode -(a2-b2)/ squat(a2sec2t b2cosec2t)
=a2-b2/squat(a2sec2t b2cosec2t)
then
Differential of this function respect t
dl/dt=a2-b2(b2cos4t-a2sin4t)/(a2sin2t b2cosec2t)3/2
for max. lenth
dl/dt=0
b2cos4t-a2sin4t =0
tant=squat(b/a)
now
d2l/dt2=(a2-b2)(-4sintcost)[(a2sin2t b2cos2t)3/2]
now
 d2l/dt2 on tant=squat(b/a)                                                  ' .'sint=squat(b/a b),cost=squat(a/a b)
    =  -4(a-b)a2b2   <0    ;.a>b 
so the lenth of normal will max. on t=tan(inverse)squat(b/a)
now
 l=a2-b2/squat(a2sec2t b2cosec2t)
 l(max.)=  a2-b2/squat{a2(a b/a) b2(a b?b)           ;.sect=squat{(a b)/a,},cosect=squat{(a b)/b}   because tant=squat(b/a)
             =  a2-b2/squat{(a b)(a b)}
              = a2-b2/a b
               =a-b