# Find max distance from $(0,0)$ to line defined on ellipse.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have got a following problem :

$E = \{ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1 \}$

$N$ - line (normal) perpendicular to E at $(x_0,y_0)$

Find max $dist(N,(0,0))$

So I am starting with attempt to find a tangent line to E at $(x_0,y_0)$. We shall call this line K.

$ K = \{ Df(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0,y-y_0) = 0\}$

$ ( \frac{2x}{a^2}(x_0,y_0), \frac{2y}{b^2}(x_0,y_0))(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ = 0

$ \frac{2x_0}{a^2}(x-x_0) + \frac{2y_0}{b^2}(y-y_0) = 0$

$ \frac{2xx_0}{a^2} - \frac{2(x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{2yy_0}{b^2} - \frac{2(y_0)^2}{b^2}=0$

So, after few transformations comes :

$y = - \frac{xx_0b^2}{a^2y_0} + \frac{(x_0)^2b^2}{a^2y_0} + y_0$

So, our line N is given by equation : $ N : y=cx+d$, $N \perp K$ at $(x_0,y_0)$

$- \frac{x_0b^2}{a^2y_0} \cdot c = -1$

$c = \frac{a^2y_0}{x_0b^2}$

$ N : y_0 = x_0 \cdot \frac{a^2y_0}{x_0b^2} +d $

$d = y_0 - \frac{a^2y_0}{b^2}$

So, our N is defined by $ y = \frac{a^2y_0}{x_0b^2}x + y_0 - \frac{a^2y_0}{b^2}$

distance from point to line is given by equation $$ dist(Ax+By+C,(x_1,y_1)) = \frac{|Ax_1+By_1+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

So I get, hmmm

$$f(x_0,y_0) = \frac{|y_0 - \frac{a^2y_0}{b^2}|}{\sqrt {\frac{a^4(y_0)^2}{(x_0)^2b^4} +1}}$$

I get confused right here. I also tried to put new line coming out from (0,0), parallel to K and perpendicular to N $ L : y = - \frac{x_0b^2}{a^2y_0}x$.

When I tried to solve equation $$ - \frac{x_0b^2}{a^2y_0}x = \frac{a^2y_0}{x_0b^2}x + y_0 - \frac{a^2y_0}{b^2}$$
 It wasn't any better. I am stuck.

Comment: Did you mean $\min$ distance? Because the maximal distance of any line and the origin is infinity since the line is infinitely long.

Comment: Well I have calculated that max dist is $|a|$, assumed $a>b$ and both $>0$

Comment: The maximum distance of the normal from the center of the ellipse is $|a-b|\,$. See G.Klambauer _Aspects of Calculus_ (1986), exercise 4.56, p. 244 .

Comment: I have found something like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305534/max-distance-of-normal-to-ellipse-from-origin. What do you think?

Comment: Anyway. I see that analytic way I have choosen is not so easy as I would have thought.